# Is it possible to modify record return by QSqlQuery select query?

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

Is it possible to modify record returned by QSqlQuery select query?
I have something like this:

```
QSqlQuery query(database);
query.prepare('Select * from `table`);
query.exec();

query.seek(15);
query.record().setValue("columName", "newValue");
```

I am trying to change data in query result with the setValue method. But it does not work. query.record().field("columnName").isReadOnly() returns false;

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

UPD:

As I see, it is not possible. Let's look at record() getter:

```
QSqlRecord QSqlQuery::record() const
{
    QSqlRecord rec = d->sqlResult->record();

    if (isValid()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rec.count(); ++i)
            rec.setValue(i, value(i));
    }
    return rec;
}
```

We get a copy of real record. 
Maybe we should use QSqlResult->record() - but it is private. Is it fine, if I will make it public for my purpose?

Any advice?

Comment: What's "a real record"? Write 'UPDATE' query if you want to update existing record.

Comment: 1. I have something like model wrapper. This wrapper operates with cache. For example query returns 500.000 rows. I don't want to store them in memory. So I just create QSqlQuery on heap and don't destroy it after execution. 
I know what data portion my view need, so I copy this portion from QSqlQuery to my cache.

2. Now user edit some field. I change data in cache. I execute Update query and change data in database. But data in executed QSqlQuery is not changed. I need to change it too.

The question is how to change data in executed QSqlQuery. Maybe another better approach exists?

Comment: Your query on heap is also in the memory... Think about using a Model (Custom) which has select and update for the database. If these are all in one table you would be fine with ``QSqlTableModel``. With a custom model you could just keep a portion of your required data and dynamically free and allocate as you like. Do you want to display the whole data? Will you require the whole data to be loaded at once?

Comment: The data is in database. Database can only be modified by appropriate query: UPDATE, DELETE, etc.

Comment: @SebastianLange, I need data from several tables. I dont want to load it all at once. QSqlTableModel is lazy model, but it can only add data to memory, and does not free it. So when we scroll to the end of TableView, we'll have all the data in memory.

Comment: @SebastianLange I also have different where clauses, so I want to execute query only one time. Query records are not fully in application memory. As I understand - it is something like a results cursor.

Comment: @user4419802, QSqlQuery after executing gives me access to records. Where are that records located? How does next(), prev() works? I execute Update query, but selected records are not affected with this (but data in database is actualy changed)

Comment: What you have is QSqlResult. 'Query' is what client (you) sends to server; 'Result' is what server sends to client. If you change 'Result', server data is not changed; if you send new 'Query', server sends new 'Result' (but previous results are not changed). Clear?

Comment: @user4419802, certainly it is clear to me.

Comment: @user4419802, as I mentioned above - I need to change data in 3 places - in my cache, in database and in query results. The problem is that I don't know how to edit data in query result. 
I don't know exactly how QSqlQuery stores query results.

Comment: @user4419802, as I see, query results are stored in database backend and we have access to some cursor. We can move this cursor via next(), prev(), seek(), etc - and get record under cursor with record(). Is it possible to change this record? I hoped Update query will change data in database and cursor will give me updated data.

Comment: Why not just UPDATE and re-SELECT? Any other solution would be error-prone. Remember that DBMS may be accessed by other users too, so relying too much on self-made cache is certainly a bad idea. You can use DBMS native transactions if you want to pack many little changes into one.

Comment: @user4419802, we have a lot of data in database, so re-selecting is not best way for us. That is why I am relying on own cache. Syncronization problem between users is solved.

Maybe better way, will be to select data, using limits and offset. I will measure it's speed on my data.

Comment: So you are trying to re-invent the wheel (DBMS cache), because your query is _bad_ (it returns more data than you need). Just re-write your query(s), and stop wasting the time trying to do what you should not.

Comment: @user4419802, maybe you are right. But is it possible to change data in DBMS cache? Just for fun.  :)

Comment: What means "change data in DBMS cache"? Do you want to break the engine completely? ;-) You simply send data to the server. When server actually writes changes onto the disk - that depends upon the server's internals. If you just want to play with some "virtual buffer", you should use transaction mechanism.

Comment: @user4419802, seems that I just need magic...

DBMS cache it is just a data buffer. We get cursor to data in this buffer. Why is it not possible to change data in this buffer? =)

Comment: CURSOR is like "a pointer" to a statement. Statements starting from 'SELECT' are "read-only". So think it to be "const void *".

Comment: @user4419802, ok. thanks. You opened a wide new field of unkown info for me.

Comment: SQL is the world of its own. If really need, well, it's possible to use explicit cursors for data update (like const_cast<>). Like "CURSOR IS SELECT x FOR UPDATE y", yet I doubt it's what you want.

Comment: @user4419802, yep. You are right. I would better solve this via other arhitecture solution. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72852/discussion-between-artem-e-and-user4419802).